# Randomizer always returns first value

Tags: javascript, random

My mother is a teacher, and I have decided to make her a random student picker (2nd Grade). My problem is that it keeps returning one student. Daniel. I set it up to log to the console what random number is returned, and it always returns Daniel even when the random number is not 1. A simple enough task, or so I thought. Background information - there are 26 students, and she teaches in Denver (Large population with lots of strange names).

```
  function studPick() {  
  var random = Math.random() * 100 / 3.84615384615  

  var rand = Math.ceil(random * 1)/1;
  console.log("rand = " + rand + ".");
  if (rand = 1) {
    var student = "Daniel";
  }
  else if (rand = 2) {
    var student = "Judge";
  }
  else if (rand = 3)
  {
    var student = "Jonathan";
  }
  else if (rand = 4) {
    var student = "John";
  }
  else if (rand = 5) {
    var student = "Amethyst";
  }
  else if (rand = 6) {
    var student = "Noah";
  }
  else if (rand = 7) {
    var student = "Antonio";
  }
  else if (rand = 8) {
    var student = "Ramon";
  }
  else if (rand = 9) {
    var student = "Aidan";
  }
  else if (rand = 10) {
    var student = "Manuel";
  }
  else if (rand = 11) {
    var student = "Ingrid";
  }
  else if (rand = 12) {
    var student = "Anastasia";
  }
  else if (rand = 13) {
    var student = "Annabella";
  }
  else if (rand = 14) {
    var student = "Christella";
  }
  else if (rand = 15) {
    var student = "La'Kym";
  }
  else if (rand = 16) {
    var student = "Isabella";
  }
  else if (rand = 17) {
    var student = "Hadiyah";
  }
  else if (rand = 18) {
    var student = "Jersey S";
  }
  else if (rand = 19) {
    var student = "Aviana";
  }
  else if (rand = 20) {
    var student = "Zion";
  }
  else if (rand = 21) {
    var student = "Carlos";
  }
  else if (rand = 22) {
    var student = "Loren";
  }
  else if (rand = 23) {
    var student = "Irie";
  }
  else if (rand = 24) {
    var student = "Trinidad"
  }
  else if (rand = 25) {
    var student = "Jersey W"
  }
  else if (rand = 26) {
    var student = "Stella"
  }
  else {
    alert("An error has occured");
  }
  alert("Randomly picked student: " + student + ".")
}
```

Edit: I suspect that my problem is that I am redefining an already defined variable. I will check that, and delete my question if that is the solution.

Comment: i think you should first learn js man

Comment: Krab... Do you think I made this without background knowledge of JS? *sighs*

Comment: should use a switch statement.

Comment: @jack_dalton15 Given you're assigning values to rand instead of comparing.. yes.

Comment: Fortunately, the max is 26 ...

Comment: Can someone give me an example of a switch statement?

Comment: @jack_dalton15 There's one below.

Comment: @jack_dalton15: Jay did, in his answer.

Comment: Even easier would be create an array of students, generate a random [integer from 0 to students.length - 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) (see 3rd example) and choose that student index from the array.

Comment: @Amadan: yes you are right, no block scope, i edited the comment

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/notionparallax/9317883 ?

Comment: @georgestocker - what is unclear about this question?  He stated what he expected the code to do and what it is actually doing and posted the relevant code. Seems clear to me. I'm not sure how it required a moderator stepping in and acting unilaterally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your #1 mistake is writing `=` where you mean `==`. `rand = 8` means "make `rand` have a value of `1`"; whereas you want `rand == 8`, "is `rand` equal to `8`?".

Your program would be much, much easier and shorter if you used arrays, though.

```
var students = ["Daniel", "Judge", "Jonathan"];
var randomStudentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length);
var student = students[randomStudentIndex];
```

(There is an additional quirk of JavaScript having `===`, which is not that important here, but can bite you in the proverbial buttocks later, so be sure to learn the difference later. It would actually be better to test everything with `===` and not `==` until you know why you'd use `==`.)